# I am trying to install utorrent in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gui, localhost, utorrent

when i enter a `localhost:8080/gui` the appear a the following prompt windows. When i enter a **admin**admin in `**UserName**` field and leave blank password field but failed the login process.

How to solve that problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you leave the password field blank?

Comment: i saw many tutorial there is no enter a password in password field

Comment: Care to share with us the tutorial you've been following? Please [edit] your question and add. And while you're at that please also tell us why you're trying to use uTorrent when any Ubuntu comes with at least one very good torrent client already.